# Why does the following loop not work as intended? Details below:

Tags: python, loops, break

Here's the code:

```
for x in range(1,15):
    flag = 0
   for b in range (1,15):
      if tagname1[x]== tagname2[b]:
         flag = 1 
         if int(aapos1[b]) <= int(aapos[x])<= int(aapos2[b]): 
            snps = snps + 1 
         elif int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 
            nonsyn2 = nonsyn2 + 1
            break
         elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 
            syn2 = syn2 + 1
            break  
      if flag == 0:  
         if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 
            nonsyn2 = nonsyn2 + 1
            break
         elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 
            syn2 = syn2 + 1
            **break**
```

When I print the value for snps, I end up getting a value of 0, which shouldn't be the case. I looked the data myself and it should produce a value of 3. If i erase the last 'break' operator that I bolded, then it works just fine, however that last break needs to be there for me to get a correct value for syn2 and I'm not sure why having the break there would affect the preceding loop from working properly. Can any suggest what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Aapos is a value in file # 1. Aapos1 and aapos2 are 2 values in file # 2, so in the code, I'm checking whether for a given tagname in file 1, whether the aapos number associated with that tagname falls between aapos1 and aapos2 (given that the tagname in file # 1 is equal to file # 2, as set by the first if statement). Therefore, for every tagname in file # 1 (tagname(x)), I want the program to go through every single tagname in file # 2 and see if the two criteria I have set (by the first two if statements) are met. If so, then I want snp + 1. But for some reason, the program is not iterating through every single tagname in file # 2, it's only iterating through the first one. I have tested this. So, my guess is that the positioning of the last break statement is causing this problem because once I remove it, it works fine. However, I don't see why that last break statement would be causin this problem.

Thanks!!

Comment: Since you don't tell us what synonymous or appos are or what the expected results are, there's no way to guess what the trouble is.

Comment: There is nothing named `snp` in the code you gave.  Do you mean `snps`?  Please put more care into asking a question that *might* have an answer ;-)

Comment: Updated. And yes, I meant snps.

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer, but I think @samrap's edit might have broken the code. In the original, the second **for** loop was indented at the same level as `flag = 0`. The edit indented only the first loop to include it in the code block. Doesn't that change it from a nested loop into a separate loop?

Comment: I think you're right @AdiInbar however the OP copy-pasted this code as a block, and each line has some strange indents if you click 'edit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at an iteration of your inner loop.  It depends on the value of synonymous[x] ... that's not included, but I am guessing it is either 1 or 0.

So... flag = 0.

if the tags match... set flag 1, check your count condition, then check syn[x] and break either way.

if the tags don't match... check syn[x] and break either way.

There are 5 possible results of a loop through the inner loop... and 4 of them result in breaking the loop.  Either you match on the first try, or you break.  I don't know nearly enough about your logic to FIX the problem, but I am pretty sure that is not what you intended.

EDIT

You want something like this...

```
for x in range(1,15):
    for y in range(1,15):
        if tag1 == tag2:
            snps += 1
if syn == 0:
    something
elif syn == 1:
    something else
```

Comment: Ya, I see what my problem is. What I want to do is for a given match between tagname1 and tagname2 across the 2 files, I want it to go through all values in file 2 and see if aapos (in file 1) falls between aapos1 and aapos2 (in file 2). ONLY if after searching the entire file it is unable to find a match, then I want to execute those elif statements and break. Right now, after checking the first value, if it does't match, it executes the elif statements, but I only want the elif statements executed after it searches ALL values in the file and can't find a match. So, how can I fix the loop?

Comment: Just move the elif statements out of the loop.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I only get a value of 1 for nonsyn2 and a value of 1 for snps, regardless of the range that I specify. That means it runs through the entire loop only once and terminates.